# VBA macro to click checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA and am learning as I go along.

I'm working on a macro that opens a page in IE, logs in, and navigates to a terminal page.
I cannot figure out how to click on the button/trigger the event for the following:

```
<div class="teamsHere">
    ::before
    <div class="teamSelector">
    <div class="teamSelector">
    <div class="teamSelector">
            <input class="teamOfflineSelect" type="checkbox">
            <div id = "50572" class="teamSlide">
                <p class="teamName">Tigers, Red</p>
                <p class="teamId">550</p>
                ::after
            </div>
     </div>
    <div class="teamSelector">
```

I've tried this

```
objIE.Document.getElementsById("50572").Click
```

this

```
objIE.Document.getElementsById("50572").getElementsByClassName("teamSlide")(0).Click
```

this

```
objIE.Document.getElementsByInnerText("550").Click
```

this

```
For Each i in objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("p")
    If i.innerText = "550" Then
        i.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

I've also tried the above with `i.innerText = "Tigers, Red"`

Comment: Try please `.checked = true` instead of `.click`

Comment: @FaneDuru unfortunately that did not work

Comment: If not confidential or inaccesibil because of another reason, can you share the  site to be processed by your code?

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to click the checkbox?  Also `getElementsById` is not a valid method - should be `getElementById`

Comment: @FaneDuru The site is confidential, but I can describe it. After logging in, I click on an icon that triggers a widget on the side of the screen. The widget has two drop down menus, one on top that is closed and one below it that is open. The open menu shows 10 boxes in a 5x2 array. Each box contains a checkbox and a name. Clicking anywhere in the box loads information for that name. My code navigates to the widget screen but does not click on any of the boxes (I wish to select the box in column 1 row 2)

Comment: @TimWilliams I've tried getElementById to no avail. I'm unsure how to reference the checkbox

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("50572").previousSibling.click` or something like that

Comment: @TimWilliams No dice. Looking at the page properties, there isn't a `previousSibling.` I tried `nextSibling` as well to no avail.

Comment: You try to click a div tag but you need to check the input tag. If it is the only one with the CSS class name *teamOfflineSelect* you can do it with **objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("teamOfflineSelect")(0).Checked = True** (0) means the first element with that class name. If there are more, you need the right index. You can also do it with *previousSibling* like Tim wrote **objIE.document.getElementById("50572").previousSibling.Checked = True**

Comment: @Zwenn the first option worked to check the box but how do I click it? I tried `objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("teamOfflineSelect")(2).Click but that doesn't work

Comment: A checkbox has no click event. So you can click how often you want, nothing will happen. If it is checked ... thats what a checkbox is for. If something else happens when you check the box manually, there is another event that triggers something. Call up the page in your browser, press F12 and click to the appropriate place in the DOM tree. If you can see other events at the end of the line (in FF click button with the word *Event*) then tell us which